# CORS Header Fails with AWS - Cloudfront, S3, and W3TotalCache

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cors, amazon-cloudfront, cdn

** Resolved - the issue here was that the DNS record for cloudfront had been specified as a TXT record. Changing this to a CNAME resolved the issues. If anyone can offer any insight as to why this minor tweak fixed the seemingly unrelated error with the font files I'm all ears :)

So I've been reading through just about everything on this topic, and I'm kind of lost as to how it can be so complicated.

I'm using a css library for some cryptocurrency icons which has a statement like this:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "cryptocoins";
  src: url('cryptocoins.woff2') format('woff2'),
    url('cryptocoins.woff') format('woff'),
    url('cryptocoins.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

These are local paths, as cryptocoins.css is in the same folder as the .ttf, .woff, .woff2 files. While everything else in my entire app is loading quickly and without any security issues, for these files I'm seeing errors in the debug console;

```
Access to Font at 'https://s3.archive/path/to/cryptocoins.woff2' from origin 'https://siteurl.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://siteurl.com' is therefore not allowed access.
Access to Font at 'https://s3.archive/path/to/cryptocoins.woff' from origin 'https://siteurl.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://siteurl.com' is therefore not allowed access.
Access to Font at 'https://s3.archive/path/to/cryptocoins.ttf' from origin 'siteurl.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'siteurl.com' is therefore not allowed access.
```

So I tested the URLs to see if they actually resolve properly with

```
curl -sI -H "Origin: https://siteurl.com" -H "Access-Control-Request-Method: GET" https://s3.archive/path/to/cryptocoins.ttf
```

and I got back the following message which I believe indicates everything is working as expected:

```
HTTP/2 200 
content-type: application/vnd.ms-opentype
content-length: 96448
date: Fri, 13 Apr 2018 18:58:48 GMT
access-control-allow-origin: https://siteurl.com
access-control-allow-methods: GET
access-control-allow-credentials: true
last-modified: Fri, 13 Apr 2018 18:29:48 GMT
etag: "kjscvsnxcjsccfa8534790552cfc79"
accept-ranges: bytes
server: AmazonS3
vary: Origin,Access-Control-Request-Headers,Access-Control-Request-Method
age: 1759
x-cache: Hit from cloudfront
via: 1.1 correct_id_code.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
x-amz-cf-id: klsvndjlkJnlkjaNbVr0UaiWSQ177ATa2TchQ1nu1pU8WkrqQ==
```

My S3 Bucket has the following CORS config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">

<CORSRule>
<AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
<AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
<AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>

</CORSConfiguration>
```

Cloudfront protocol behaviour settings:

```
Origin:                        https://s3.archive
Viewer Protocol Policy:        Redirect HTTP to HTTPS

Allowed HTTP Methods:        GET, HEAD, OPTIONS, PUT, POST, PATCH, DELETE
```

Whitelist headers:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin
Access-Control-Max-Age
Access-Control-Request-Headers
Access-Control-Request-Method
Origin
```

I really feel like this should be working based on the curl result, so I'm thinking there must be an issue with the way the .ttf, .woff, and .woff2 files are accessed by the .css.

I'm thinking there has to be a way to resolve this, but haven't been able to quite get it. Any thoughts or suggestions would be really appreciated.

Comment: You are not using this the way you intended, or you've made an error while sanitizing your URLs, or I am reading something here incorrectly.  Your CORS error mentions `https://s3.archive...` yet you claim to be using CloudFront, pointed to this bucket... but if that were true, this wouldn't even be a cross-origin request.

Comment: Hi michael - I actually found my error. 

The setup here uses an S3 bucket to host static content (css, js, images) and the cloudfront distribution is just acting as a caching layer.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here was that the DNS record for cloudfront had been specified as a TXT record. Changing this to a CNAME resolved the issues. If anyone can offer any insight as to why this minor tweak fixed the seemingly unrelated error with the font files I'm all ears :)